# Why can't I import Content into SenseNet that has multiple Choices selected?

Tags: c#, xml, sensenet

I have a Content definition (CTD) in SenseNet that has a Choice field that allows multiple values to be selected (`AllowMultiple` is true). The XML definition looks like this:

```
<Field name="Status" type="Choice">
  <DisplayName>Status</DisplayName>
  <Configuration>
    <AllowMultiple>true</AllowMultiple>
    <Options>
      <Option>In Processing</Option>
      <Option>In Review</Option>
      <Option>Tabled</Option>
      <Option>Pending Verification</Option>
      <Option>Approved</Option>
    </Options>
  </Configuration>
</Field>
```

When I export the data with multiple Options selected, the XML output for this field delimits the choice options with `;` (semi-colon + space) and looks something like this:

```
<Status>Pending Verification; Approved</Status>
```

When I try to import the exported data I get an `InvalidExtraValue` error.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here has to do with the space after the semi-colon in the exported XML data. The import function in SenseNet splits the XML data string by looking for either comma or semi-colon delimiters, and then returns a `List<string>` collection of the values. As you might have guessed, the leading space is not removed and this results in a failed comparison to the valid choice options.

There are two ways to resolve this issue; you can either change your data, or modify the source code.

**Change Your Data**

You can run a script to modify your exported data so that all the leading spaces are removed, so that this

```
<Status>Pending Verification; Approved</Status>
```

is changed to this:

```
<Status>Pending Verification;Approved</Status>
```

**Modify the Source Code**

If you can compile the SenseNet source code, you will need to modify the function `ConvertToStringList` in file `ChoiceFields.cs` in the folder `Source\SenseNet\ContentRepository\Fields`. Just make sure all the strings added to the returned list are trimmed (`String.Trim()`).

Replace this function with the code below, rebuild the project, and the import will work correctly -- you will not need to change your data.

```
    public static List<string> ConvertToStringList(object value)
    {
        List<string> list = value as List<string>;
        if (list != null)
            return list.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();

        list = new List<string>();
        string stringValue = value as string;
        if (stringValue != null)
        {
            list.Add(stringValue);
        }
        else
        {
            IEnumerable enumerableValue = value as IEnumerable;
            if (enumerableValue == null)
            {
                list.Add(value.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (object item in enumerableValue)
                    list.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
        return list.Select(s => s.Trim()).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: This code is garbage.  Why would you want to convert a string to a List<string>?  Why would object sometimes be a string and other times a List<string>   I suspect the real issue is that the import method thinks the semicolon is part of an html special character.  See : https://www.google.com/search?q=wiki+xml+html+special+characters&rlz=1C1OPRA_enUS563US647&oq=wiki+xml+html+special+characters&aqs=chrome..69i57.15711j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: The code may not be as readable as one would like, however, it's pretty much straight from the source. In these cases it's essential not to change the behavior of the function, and that's what you're seeing. If you understood the SenseNet Content model, you would know why it has to take an object parameter, which may be a string, IEnumerable, or List. Your suspicions on the problem are incorrect; the code as written address the issue.

Comment: The answer is ok, the different type conversions are sensenet-related, they are by design. A third option would be to use values for the options (attributes in the ctd). That way you could use human readable option texts and option values without space at the same time.